# copy constructor of a linked list class

Tags: c++, linked-list

i have a linked list class List. i have to make a copy constructor for it. i am actually having problem with the syntax. here is my code:

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
}
```

otherList is another item of type List. infact i think it is a pointer to a List. i have a getHead() function defined for class List and its works fine.
i thought doing the following will be ok:

```
Node* temp = otherList->getHead();
```

node is the pointer of which the List is composed. this is a separate class Node.
but doing the above gives the error:

```
base operand of -> has non-pointer type const List<int>
```

so i tried using "." instead of "->" in the above expression. got the following error:

```
passing const List<int> as this argument of ListItem<T>* List<T>::getHead() [with T = int] discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

my getHead function:

```
template <class T>
node<T>* List<T>::getHead()
{
return head;
}
```

kindly guide me

Comment: What makes you think its a pointer?

Comment: The foreign list reference is const. thus you can only use const members of it, and data members you retrieve from it are said-same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `otherList` is not a pointer, it's a "reference to `const List<T>`". We know it's a reference because of the `&` in its type. If it were a pointer, it would have a `*` in its type. A reference behaves exactly as if you just had the object itself. So using `.` to access its member function `getHead` is correct.

Now the problem is that you have a `const` reference, but you're calling a non-`const` member function. As far as the compiler is concerned, your `getHead` function might modify the `List` and so shouldn't be called on a `const List`. You need to declare `getHead` as being `const`. Wherever you have the declaration of `getHead`, stick a `const` before the `{` that begins the function:

```
template <typename T>
const Node<T>* List<T>::getHead() const {
  // ...
}
```

This assumes that `getHead` doesn't actually modify the list (which it shouldn't). If it does, then you can't make it a `const` member function and can't call it from your copy constructor because the `otherList` is `const`. However, your copy constructor should never modify the object it is copying, so your `otherList` *should* be `const`.

Comment: i did what you pointed out . but i am getting the same error :

Comment: passing const List as this argument of ListItem* List::getHead() [with T = int] discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: +1, and Sorry, rabbit, that likely should have been `const List<T>::Node*`, but again, without code from the OP, hard saying. Assuming `Node` is a nested class of `List<T>` that would be correct. Otherwise what you have is.

Comment: Node is a class and the linked list class conatins node* head which is then linked to further node* 's.

Comment: @khurramusman then this code is correct as-is and your target pointer should be declared as `const Node<T>*` in your copy-ctor.

Comment: i declared the target pointer as const but sill getting the same error.

Comment: @rabbit: error: passing قconst List<int>ق as قthisق argument of قListItem<T>* List<T>::getHead() [with T = int]ق discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @khurramusman Did you put `const` after your declaration of `getHead` like I said? Look carefully at my example. There's a `const` after `getHead()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that `getHead()` should be declared a const function... Try it and let us know if it works or not.